# The cross on Feynman diagrams

Tags: particle-physics, renormalization, notation, feynman-diagrams, supersymmetry

In figure (a), in the upper part of the loop, What is the meaning of the cross between smuon and the node of selectron and photino?

[image]

Comment: Crosses usually mean counterterm insertions, but without a reference we cannot know for sure.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not that comfortable around quantum field theory so countertermes aren't that known to me yet your answer gave me the small push that I need to dig deep and for context I'm reading g-2 articles to understand a bit behind Charged lepton flavor violation interactions

Comment: Context, like what author/book is still relevant here and should be added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing. In this case the smuon on the left of the cross turns into a selectron to the right of the cross. The selectron then radiates the photino.

Comment: yes, but no need for the cross if that was just the case? I think the answer was given by @DavideMorgante